# Python: Decoding byte array

Tags: python, arrays, encoding, base64, decoding

can someone tell me how to decode this bytearray:

`` bytearray(b"~QF\xc2\x13\x04\xca=`\xc3\xef\xfd\x8bc\xb3\xcf\'V\xa3n\xeb\xccX\x97\xb2\xe6\xe0\xca\x12\x85\xac\x8b\xca\xd3hj\xb3\xc0\xedF\x84\x91\x83\t\xfe:\xdd@\xeb?O\xf8\xc2\xf1,\x8d\xfc\x1ag\xddZ\xd0\x14\xcc") ``

I've tried everything I can think of. Different ways of `value.decode()` where I used different encodings (utf-8, utf-16-le, windows-1252, ascii, the list goes on) and base64 encodings (last I tried was base64.b64decode since it truncates the padding).

I've an example of the decoding in an NodeJS application:
`Buffer.from(bluetoothBarrier.getReceivedMessage()).toString('base64')`

But I don't know how to replicate this in Python...

Comment: Are you sure it has text? Do you have an idea on what it should contain? And which language? It helps us to try to decipher it.

Comment: If it came from Bluetooth, surely you need a decoder for that protocol, not for a text encoding.

Comment: It definitely should contain text. A string like "RESPONSE_CODE-MESSAGE-AUTH_STATUS".

Comment: The bluetooth example did the decoding with utf-8. But that throws an error for me.
`'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 3: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: It has a `C0` byte so for sure it is not UTF-8, but it seems also not ASCII based encoding, nor UTF-16, and not old ISO shift encodings. But as you see in NodeJS, you need a function which decode BlueTooth, and probably it has much BT logic on there). So reimplement it in Python or look for a similar functions

Comment: when I run `b'\xc2'.decode('latin1')` then I get `Â` so it is not `UTF8` but `latin1` or similars. `cp1252` also gives `Â`. This may have few encodings at the same time - ie. `latin1` and `base64`

Comment: when I use `base64.b64encode(your_bytes)` then I get `b'@W\x15\x9dxc\x14\xe8\x19'` - so this `bytes` seems correc `base64` but it have different content than you expect. Maybe system use some method to compress message before converting to `base64`

Comment: To help I think we would need to know about how you have reproduced `bluetoothBarrier.getReceivedMessage()` in python as I assume that is the bytearray you have in your question. From what you've said in the comments it is likely it is using binary protocol having all values as bytes, as opposed to a text-based protocol which only uses values corresponding to human-readable characters in ASCII encoding.

Comment: I had some wrong informations when I created the question. I just need to encode the bytearray do nothing more. So I don't need to face the above mentioned problems anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
Buffer.from(bluetoothBarrier.getReceivedMessage()).toString('base64')
```

This appears to be converting the received message into a base64 string.

If that's all you want to do the correct implementation would be:

```
base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(bytesarray)
base64_string = base64_bytes.decode('utf-8')
```

This produces base64 encode string:

```
'flFGwhMEyj1gw+/9i2OzzydWo27rzFiXsubgyhKFrIvK02hqs8DtRoSRgwn+Ot1A6z9P+MLxLI38GmfdWtAUzA=='
```

Comment: I now did find out, that it was AES encrypted. After decrypting I get the following bytearray: `b'\xc2_\xc9\x85\xdf\xf7\r\x1e\xbc\xa0\xd2\xf9i\xb6\x14\xc5\x1d/\x19U\xef\x15n\x8a\xaf\xb5\xb2\xa3\x11cW\xd1\xb1\xa3\x0c\xdb"\x85\xfc\x95CM\xf2\x80E\xe6M+\xaf.\xda\xc3\xbarX\'\xdaI\xdfIS\x8f\xbc\xfc'` 
But it isn't utf-8 or latin1 encoded. I don't know which encoding I now need to get it into a  human readable string.